# After importing a module in ReactJS npm start wont compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using create-react-app to build a simple gallery based on reddit API using [reddit.js](https://github.com/sahilm/reddit.js)

I used `npm install --save reddit.js` in the "C:....\reddit-gallery"

I wrote some basic code, and when using `npm start` to run it, I keep getting:

> Failed to compile.
>
> Error in ./src/App.js
>
> C:....\reddit-gallery\src\App.js
>
> 18:9  error  'reddit' is not defined  no-undef

While coding it is recognizing the library, but when using npm it does not recognize any code from that library

The code:

```
import 'reddit.js';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {};

    this.loadSubreddit = this.loadSubreddit.bind(this);
}

loadSubreddit(subre){
    reddit.hot(subre)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(json => {
            console.log(json)
    })

}

componentWillMount() {
    console.log('comp is mounting');
    this.loadSubreddit('cats');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This library is not prepared as module so you are not able to import it. You can only include it via `<script>` tag on the HTML page.

Comment: it is passing the npm start
but getting "TypeError: _reddit2.default.hot is not a function"
in npm test and in the console

Comment: Don't understand you. According to the `CommonJS` you have to define the name of a reference you'd like to load it to? By statement `import 'reddit.js'` you may load the library, but you can't use it as you don't have any reference to it.

Comment: Also you have to understand, that node.js in CLI mode doesn't have the `window` object and you can't just call `reddit` from it in this case, like in browser.

Comment: what do you mean by "define the name of a reference you'd like to load"?

Comment: Have a look to the answer. Most npm modules are importing in this way. In this case you should define the variable `reddit` (for example) and import the module "to it". Then you'll be able to call the module via this variable.

Comment: i think i am getting there, correct me if i am wrong,
in order to use "import reddit from 'reddit.js';"
i need to export it from reddit.js?
currently i am getting a notice from it "default export is not declared"

Comment: You are right. Look at the README `Reddit.js is a browser based wrapper`. Really, according to the code, the library is for browser-usage only. You are not able to use it in CLI. The only thing you can do is to include it via a common `script` tag at the page directly.

Comment: Have changed my answer.